# SSH Tunneling using libssh2

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to do a SSH-TUNNEL trough `libssh2`. Till now i was doing it with this command :

```
server# sshpass -p password ssh -vvv username@1.2.3.4 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -N -D 1.2.3.4:5555
```

the `-D 1.2.3.4:5555` is used to open the tunnel on internet on that port then i go and use it with `CURL` :

```
server# curl --SOCKS5 "1.2.3.4:5555" "www.somesite.com"
-- content of the website --
```

Now i am trying to do the same, but with `libssh2`, thus i need to do it in `C/C++`

I tried both examples from `libssh2`

**direct_tcpip.c** -> https://www.libssh2.org/examples/direct_tcpip.html

```
Fingerprint: 5D 75 A3 D9 10 65 D5 C4 6B CA 37 98 26 33 53 24 F8 19 1B F9
Authentication methods: publickey,password
Waiting for TCP connection on 1.2.3.4:5555...
Forwarding connection from 1.2.3.4:58595 here to remote 1.2.3.4:22
read: Connection reset by peer <-- When I use curl command
```

and

**tcpip-forward.c** -> https://www.libssh2.org/examples/tcpip-forward.html

```
Fingerprint: 5D 75 A3 D9 10 65 D5 C4 6B CA 37 98 26 33 53 24 F8 19 1B F9
Authentication methods: publickey,password
Waiting for TCP connection on 1.2.3.4:5555...
Forwarding connection from 1.2.3.4:58595 here to remote 1.2.3.4:22
The remote client at 1.2.3.4:5555 disconnected! <-- When I use curl command
```

and curl command :

`server# curl --SOCKS5 "1.2.3.4:5555" "somesite.com"
 curl: (7) Received invalid version in initial SOCKS5 response.`

What is the problem? Is `libssh2` capable of tunneling or not?

P.S. The project is compatible `C/C++`, that's why I put two tags.

Comment: If it can compile in C it is a C project not c++. Also can you please put your code (cleaned up and only what is needed) in the question directly?

Comment: it can compile with `gcc` and `g++` what makes it? Also the code is on the internet, never touched it, it supposed to do a tunnel, but it is not working

Comment: If you don't have a coding problem then best ask the people from libssh and not stackoverflow. And it compiles in g++ because g++ can also compile C code/ C-code is valid in c++. But that is true for every C program (with some syntactic exceptions). So you should only flag this c++ if you also use c++ featues.

Comment: i think i better flag this as `C` thus all files are like `libssh2_example.c` and mainly if you carefully read you see that libssh is for `C` ... but seems to work with no problems in `C++` ...